# How do I use Reactor's StepVerifier to verify a Mono is empty?

Tags: java, unit-testing, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am using `StepVerifier` to test values:

```
@Test
public void testStuff() {
    Thing thing = new Thing();
    Mono<Thing> result = Mono.just(thing);
    StepVerifier.create(result).consumeNextWith(r -> {
        assertEquals(thing, r);
    }).verifyComplete();
}
```

What I'd like to do now is test for the absence of an item in the Mono.  Like this:

```
@Test
public void testNoStuff() {
    Mono<Thing> result = Mono.empty();
    StepVerifier.create(result)... // what goes here?
}
```

I want to test that the Mono is in fact empty.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Simply use `verifyComplete()`. If the `Mono` emits any data, it will fail the stepverifier as it doesn't expect an `onNext` signal at this point.

Answer (score 19):

here it is checked that onNext is not called

```
 StepVerifier.create(result).expectNextCount(0).verifyComplete()
```

Comment: Please explain the difference to the other, older, upvoted answer. It seems that you recommend the same thing, just without any explanation

Comment: expectNextCount will be keeping track of how many elements are pending to iterate. If there is no elements in the flux/mono, it will match with 0 & the test case will pass